# Validation Rule to auto populate Date field when a picklist value is selected

Tags: validation

I have made a validation rule below to auto populate a date field to today if picklist value is selected, but this seems to be not working:

AND( Offer_Stage_Date__c > today() ) ((OR(ISPICKVAL (Offer_Stage__c, "placed"))

Can you please what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

`Validation Rules` don't populate anything, they block database operations. You want to use a `Workflow` with a `Field Update`.

Create a new `Workflow Rule`:

```
Create > Workflow & Approvals > Workflow Rules > New Rule
```

Select your object. Then you will need to give it a `Name` and define `Evaluation Criteria` and `Rule Criteria`:

[image: screenshot]

Then you need to add a `Field Update`:

[image]

Now give it a `Name`, `Unique Name`, and select the field you wish to update.

When prompted to specify a value, use a formula that evaluates to `TODAY()`:

[image]

Comment: How can i add a workflow in a custom object

Answer (score 0):

Hello Jovi for add workflow in custom object or standard object you go to setup>create>Workflow & Approvals>create and manage workflow rules>new rule>select object custom/Standard object

Thanks,
Pritam Shekhawat